# How to mock parts of a service and test others?

Tags: java, easymock

I'm using easymock, and I am mocking my UserService class.

My UserService has a few methods:

```
boolean canUserLogin(..);
boolean canUserJoinClass(...);
```

Now some of the methods call each other, and if I am testing method#1 I want to stub/mock methods #2 and methods# 3 that are called in method#1.

What I am confused is, how can I mock parts of a class and leave others to run the actual code?

So I want to actually test UserService.method#1, but mock UserService.method#2 and UserService.method#3 that method#1 calls internally.

Answer (score 3):

By specifying return values for the methods you want mocked; see the [easymock docs](http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_1_Documentation.html) for examples.

- The "Specifying Return Values" section discusses creating return values for mocked methods.
- The "Partial mocking" section (towards the bottom) discusses mocking actual classes.

I agree with the docs (and other answers) that this may be an indication of sketchy design. Without further details, it's hard to say how sketchy it is, if it is at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can check some library like Easymock, but I don't sure whether it can do this.

And here is my solution without third-party library. Create a subclass of UserService, and override the method you want to mock.

```
class SubUserService{

  @override
  boolean canUserJoinClass(...){
    return false;
  }

}
```

But notice the mock method can't be private.

And if this is one real problem you meet, you should refactor you methods to different classes.

Answer (score 1):

I know Mockito supports "spy" on real objects. I could not find an equivalent in Easy Mock. So, I am not sure if you can do this.

Having said that, this is a smell to me. Why do you need to mock it? Is that an indication of the fact that your object is doing too much and hence you need to mock the other interactions?

Also, whenever you need to worry about the implementation of a method (method 1 in this case) i.e. the fact that it calls method2 and method3, especially of the same class, that sounds to me like a encapsulation leaking.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking is intended to be used for dependencies, so you can test in isolation.  In this case, you don't have any dependencies, since the methods you are calling are on one class.  So I wouldn't use mocking here.

If methods 2 and 3 are so complicated that you want to mock them when testing method 1, then perhaps you should separate them out into their own class(es), so you can easily mock them.